# Is this a correct proof to show that a set is open in $\mathbb{Q}$ as a metric space?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces, proof-writing

Consider the set $\{p\in\mathbb{Q} \mid 2<p^2<3\}$ which I want to show is open in $\mathbb{Q}$, as a metric space. Then, any $p$ in the set is in the interval $(-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, $\exists o,q\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $-\sqrt{2}<o<p<q<\sqrt{3}$. Choose $\epsilon = \min(q-p,p-o)$. Then, $B_\epsilon(p)$, the open ball around $p$ in $\mathbb{Q} $, is contained in $\{p\in\mathbb{Q} \mid 2<p^2<3\}\implies \{p\in\mathbb{Q} \mid 2<p^2<3\}$ is open.

Is this correct? It seems awkward to look at intervals given that we are only considering the metric space as $\mathbb{Q}$.

**Edit**: If I instead look at the *correct* interval, namely $(-\sqrt{3},-\sqrt{2})\cup (\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$. Does this same approach still work?

Comment: I don't think this is correct. The set you are looking at defined in $\mathbb R$ is $(-\sqrt 3, -\sqrt 2)\cup(\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3)$. Your ball can possibly contain elements outside this set. Just because the ball is inside $(-\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3)$ does not mean its in the desired set.

Comment: @TrevorNorton you're totally correct, thank you. If I changed my strategy for that interval. Would this approach then be ok?

Comment: $(-\sqrt3, -\sqrt2)\cup (\sqrt2, \sqrt3)$ is not an interval, and there is nothing exactly analogous to your $-\sqrt 2 < o < p< q < \sqrt 3$ statement.

Comment: @MJD well, couldn't you have two cases? One where p is in the first interval and one where p is in the second interval? Then, follow the same pattern as before?

Comment: I think that approach will probably work.

Comment: Yeah, I think changing your argument to that set would work, however I kinda think it's not particularly stylish. My guess is that the assignment wants you to work only in $\mathbb Q$ rather than relying on results in $\mathbb R$. If you want to push yourself, see if you can rewrite the proof without referencing $\mathbb R$ and using only the properties of the rational numbers.

Comment: Possibly easier: note that $x\mapsto x^2$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and is therefore continuous on $\mathbb{Q}$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$, and your set is the preimage of the open set $(2, 3)$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ under the map $x\mapsto x^2$ and is therefore open.

Comment: @MichaelLee that sounds good too! Unfortunately, I am not yet allowed to use continuity.

Answer (score 0):

From the properties of the subspace topology  on $\mathbb{Q}$(and any set in general) we know that subset $A$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ is open in $(\mathbb{Q},d) \iff$ exists a set $V\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ open in $(\mathbb{R},d)$ such that $$A=\mathbb{Q} \cap V$$

Now with respect to the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$ the set $(-\sqrt{3},-\sqrt{2}) \cup (\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$

Also $\{p \in \mathbb{Q}|2<p^2<3\}=[(-\sqrt{3},-\sqrt{2}) \cup (\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})] \cap \mathbb{Q}$

Thus $\{p \in \mathbb{Q}|2<p^2<3\}$ is open in $(\mathbb{Q},d)$ where $d$ is the usual metric in $\mathbb{R}$